# Dictionary values returning invalid token

Tags: python, python-2.7

I encountered this while trying to make a dictionary.

The 8 & 9 don't work when they have `00` in front of them.
All the others do fine however. It goes the same for `019, 099`.

Using 2.7

```
b = {000 : "a", 
     001 : "b", 
     002 : "c", 
     003 : "d", 
     004 : "e", 
     005 : "f", 
     006 : "g", 
     007 : "h", 
     8 :   "i", 
     9 : "j"}
print b[001]
print b[8]
```

While this doesn't?

```
a = {000 : "a", 
     001 : "b", 
     002 : "c", 
     003 : "d", 
     004 : "e", 
     005 : "f", 
     006 : "g", 
     007 : "h", 
     008 : "i", 
     009 : "j"}
print a[001]
print a[008]
```

Comment: You are specifying octal literals, not integer literals.

Comment: Assuming you wanted integer keys, I can't help but wonder why you would do this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python 2, you can define octal literals by prefizing them with `0`. Since octal numerals only contain the digits `0-7`, `008` and `009` are invalid.

This was changed in Python 3, octal literals are now prefixed with `0o` or `0O` (digit "zero" followed by letter "O"). This is similar to the `0x` notation for hex literals, and `0b` for binary.

Answer (score 3):

You are using integer literals starting with 0, which are interpreted as octal numbers (whose digits only range from 0-7). You probably want

```
b = {'000': "a", 
     '001': "b", 
     '002': "c", 
     '003': "d", 
     '004': "e", 
     '005': "f", 
     '006': "g", 
     '007': "h", 
     '008': "i", 
     '009': "j"}
```

If the leading zeros are significant; as integers, the notation you use to specify the integer `(0, 000, 0x00, etc)` doesn't affect the actual value in anyway.